# Ubuntu boot screen flashing after update

Tags: boot, 20.04, keyboard

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 and, during the power-up, the boot screen starts to look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XALVx.jpg)(video). And takes a long time to get to the login page. This is my laptop(Dell Inspiron 15 with a nvidia 840m) and I don't use it often but I did a normal `sudo apt upgrade` before this started happening.

About 2 times I got as "A start job is running for hold until boot process finishes up(time/no limit)", now I'm not getting it.
I tried doing a `sudo apt update` and a `sudo apt upgrade`.

Also, It looks like my lap keyboard is spamming the tab key(not 100% sure on the exact key, and could be a hardware issue.) Currently, I'm using an external keyboard and disabled the inbuilt one. I'm mentioning this keyboard issue it could be connected cause both happened simultaneously.

Will removing splash screen help? Thanks.

Comment: You have a couple of possibilities. The text that you see on the screen is normally hidden, unless there's an early RED FAIL message. The Dell splash screen is displayed by recent versions of Ubuntu. First check that you've got the latest BIOS for your computer/motherboard. `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`. Keyboard issues can also cause problems.

Comment: I got the latest bios, I'll try replacing the keyboard. Maybe a key could be spamming. @heynnema Should I try removing splash screen? Will it help?

Comment: First check for RED FAIL messages on the text portion of the screen. They would appear very early, so use a camera to record the boot. You can also check `systemctl --failed`.

Comment: Well, looks like updating Nvidia drivers solves the problem. I'm not 100% sure, I'll update this after some test runs.

Comment: What version Nvidia? From what version before? Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema version before was 460 and I updated it to 470. My GPU model is GeForce 840M.